# no limit 2 lightwave object matériau output error

Tags: texturing, materials, scripting, add-on, import

I tried to import my lay out no limit using an addd on but, it gives me this error message I don't understand Could you help me please?[image]

Comment: I think you need to use a previous Blender version, or get the latest version of the addon. Either way it's next to impossible to help you here, sorry :)